# How to automatically update the Hive external table metadata partitions for streaming data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, spark-streaming, hive-partitions

I am writing the spark streaming data into hdfs partitions using pyspark.
please find the code

```
  data = (spark.readStream.format("json").schema(fileSchema).load(inputDirectoryOfJsonFiles))

  output = (data.writeStream
   .format("parquet")
   .partitionBy("date")
   .option("compression", "none")
   .option("path" , "/user/hdfs/stream-test")
   .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/hdfs/stream-ckp")
   .outputMode("append")
   .start().awaitTermination())
```

After writing the data into hdfs, i am creating the hive external partition table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (id string,record string) 
PARTITIONED BY (`date` date) 
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION '/user/hdfs/stream-test/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('discover.partitions' = 'true');
```

But the newly created partitions are not been recognized Hive metastore. i am updating the metastore using the msck command.

```
msck repair table test sync partitions
```

Now for the streaming data how to automate this task of updating the hive metastore with the real time partitions.

please suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: Why do we need MSCK repair table to refresh hive metastore? Is there any other alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Spark structured streaming don't natively support this, but you can use `foreachBatch` as workaround

```
val yourStream = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .load()

val query = yourStream.writeStream.foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
  batchDF
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .insertInto("your_db.your_hive_table");
}).start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

More details refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch